# How to maintain language specific comments after TargetFramework change

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I am going to upgrade TargetFramework for our client projects but they used French language for their development. But we are using English language over here. Now when I upgrading target framework then resource designer file comments changed from French to English.
**Resource designer** file comments in framework 4.0

```
<summary>
///   Une classe de ressource fortement typÃ©e destinÃ©e, entre autres, Ã  la consultation des chaÃ®nes localisÃ©es.
/// </summary>
```

After upgrading TargetFramework by using project properties drop down it change to

```
/// <summary>
///   A strongly-typed resource class, for looking up localized strings, etc.
/// </summary>
```

Can you please help me how can we keep **Visual Studio auto generated   comments** in French language what steps I need to take to handle this?

Is it possible that, If I install 4.5.2 framework in French and English languages in my machine. Then When I select targetframwork from drop-down at that time, I can specify which language I need to migrate French or English?

These are Custom resource files like EmployeeException.resx file. Now the content of that file does not change. it is still in french language but its designer file MEGExceptionMessages.Designer.cs has been changed to English translation. As these are supported files for Visual Studio so I think it convert automatically by that due to framework change..

Earlier it is

```
<auto-generated>
//     Ce code a Ã©tÃ© gÃ©nÃ©rÃ© par un outil.
//     Version du runtime :4.0.30319.18444
//
//     Les modifications apportÃ©es Ã  ce fichier peuvent provoquer un comportement incorrect et seront perdues si
//     le code est rÃ©gÃ©nÃ©rÃ©.
// </auto-generated>
```

After Target framework change, Now it is....

```
/ <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.34209
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
```

Comment: Well, at least they will learn English ^^

Comment: It’d be nice if a project could specify the preferred autogenerated comment language in `.editorconfig`. But I don’t think such a thing exists (yet?).

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer from on MSDN blog. You can refer following link for more details. To handle this issue, Visual Studio Language pack need to install and then select specific language setting from Tools >> Option >> International Setting.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cd7d0132-3d57-4fd7-ad42-35866c94af62/how-to-maintain-language-specific-comments-after-targetframework-change?forum=netfxbcl

Ankush

Comment: That doesn't help, as the problem is the other way round: The text should not be touched regardless of what language version of VS the current developer uses. It's rather nasty that all comments change whenever a developer with a different VS version edits the file.