# resx - Designer.cs comment language

Tags: c#, .net, git, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Our team is using different languages when using Visual Studio. (some German, some English) 
And we get everytime conflicts with the auto generated

```
eng: <summary> Looks up a localized string similar to ...
de:  <summary> Sucht eine lokalisierte Zeichenfolge,
```

comments of each corresponding resource in the Designer.cs file when we are commiting/pushing changes.

Is there a proper solution for that ?

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how you commit/pushing changes? Which tool do you use?

Comment: we use git for commiting/pushinging changes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to maintain language specific comments after TargetFramework change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31435836/how-to-maintain-language-specific-comments-after-targetframework-change)

Comment: not really, see the comment of PMF in that thread's answers.